# Can somebody help me find out what set this bag belongs to?

Tags: set-identification, piece-information

I found a Little bag from a larger set at a yard sale, and im trying to find out what set it belongs to. It comes with a bunch of lime green pieces, some are also gray and red. [image]

Answer (score 3):

Based on the parts:

- Light Bluish Gray Technic, Axle and Pin Connector Perpendicular 3L with Center Pin Hole
- Lime Technic, Axle and Pin Connector Perpendicular 3L with 2 Pin Holes
- Red Technic, Axle and Pin Connector Perpendicular Double
- Lime Slope, Curved 2 x 2 x 2/3

this must be [42138: Ford Mustang Shelby GT500](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=42138-1).

Comment: YO ty so much for the quick response!

Comment: @Sogpog You're certainly welcome! Please take a minute to read the [help] and [tour] pages to find out more about how the site works and what to do when you find an answer helpful ;)